# What is the use of this class?

Tags: c++, class

What is this class for ?

```
class EqualTo {
private:
   int target;
public:
   EqualTo(int i) : target(i) {}
   bool operator()(const int& i) const {
     return i == target;
   }
};
```

I have this class in a homework and they have used it with the `find` function just like :

```
it = list.find(EqualTo(3));
```

thanks

Comment: It is a functor that realizes a boolean predicate

Comment: Please tell me they aren't teaching this stuff...

Comment: @crush, why not? (except `i` should arguably be passed by value, not const reference, but still)

Comment: yes, they are teaching .. why ?

Comment: It's ugly. That's why.

Comment: @crush: You mean using the standard library is ugly? Or that this code doesn't meet your aesthetic standards? It doesn't look ugly to me (apart from the questionable reference parameter, and my personal preference for putting public declarations first).

Comment: I hope your teacher at least mentions `std::equal_to`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a *functor*; that is, an object that can be called like a function. It's more flexible than a function, since it can also contain state and use that when it's called. Here's an example of how to use it directly:

```
EqualTo is5(5);   // Object to test whether numbers are 5

assert(is5(5));   // Returns true:  value is 5
assert(!is5(42)); // Returns false: value is not 5
```

In this case, it takes a single value and returns a boolean to tell you whether that value satisfies some condition; a functor that does that is known as a *predicate*.

```
it = list.find(EqualTo(3));
```

This example uses a predicate to find an element in a container which matches the condition. In this case, it gives you an iterator pointing to the first element that equals 3.

Comment: Wouldn't `assert(!is5(42)); // False: is not 5` Actually assert true since `is5(42) would return false`?

Comment: @crush: Yes, that's what I meant. The functor returns `false`, so the assertion succeeds. I've clarified the comments a bit.